# Sails Waterline Model - attribute parsed as string for postgres bigint column

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

I am using Sails alongside its Waterline ORM for PostgreSQL. I am having an issue with the `defaultsTo` parameter in model attribute definition.

Here is a part of my Model definition:

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'table',

  attributes: {
    [...]
    reach: {
      type: 'number',
      defaultsTo: 0,
    }
    [...]
  }
}
```

When using `Model.create()`, I get this console warning:

```
Warning: After transforming columnNames back to attribute names for model `model`,
 a record in the result has a value with an unexpected data type for property `reach`.
The corresponding attribute declares `type: 'number'` but instead
of that, the actual value is:
` ` `
'0'
` ` `
```

I have a bunch of `number` type attributes so this leads to a lot of warnings in my console.

At this point, I believe this is a waterline issue but do you have a workaround to avoid this warning?

---

Edit

My warning is only appearing for Postgres "BIGINT" column
I am starting to undersand that JS cannot handle postgres BIGINT as number so it must be converted to string.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to avoid warning : 
set attribute a different way:

```
attributes: {
  [...]
  reach: {
    type: 'ref',
    columnType: 'bigint',
    isNumber: true,
    defaultsTo: 0
  },
  [...]
}
```

Comment: I was having this problem too! Thank you I will try this!!

Comment: My thing is I need to create time fields, like the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields, is this the way you found to accomplish this?

Comment: I tried this, however the number is still coming back as string :(